# How do Elastic Beanstalk/Heroku-based webapps discover their own addressible URLs?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

If I want to have asynchronous components of my app talk to each other via RESTful endpoints and callbacks, they need to be able to know their own URLs (protocol+hostname+port). I can think of a few ways to tell them this info via semi-hacky ways involving environment variables or post-startup commands, but I'm curious if there's any widely-used techniques to this.

Comment: EBS = Elastic Block Store, EB = Elastic Beanstalk

Comment: Whoops, thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Usually each RESTful endpoint has its own (internal) DNS name, which the other nodes know and use. As servers go up and down, they all maintain the same URL endpoint name, hence the RESTful calls remain active. This is most helpful for synchronous usage.
For asynchronous usage you'd usually use a queuing solution. In amazon you can use [AWS SNS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/welcome.html). You'd post a topic and the appropriate service would pick it up for processing.